# In VSTS How to run a 20 second webtest every 5 seconds

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance, webtest, load-testing

I have a WebPerfoamce test in Visual Studio Team System 2008, it's average execution is 20 seconds.

I have a load test that runs the test every 5 seconds using:

Test Mix Type: Based on user pace

Tests per user per hour: 720 (Which should be 12 test runs per min)

with a constant user load of 1.

The problem is when this is executed only 2 or 3 tests are run per min. I expect 11 or 12 though...

If anyone has any ideas.. please suggest away :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use a Goal Based Load Pattern targeting

Category:LoadTest:Test
Counter:Tests/Sec
Instance:_Total

I remember that a bug within 2008 meant that LoadTest:xx goals were not working, but that was pre SP1. 
I have not been able to find confirmation, but a quick test will prove/disprove that theory.

This will definitely work in Visual Studio 2010.

The goal based load patter will adjust your user load till the desired 5 test/sec is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

If the test takes 20 seconds and you only only have 1 user running, then you cannot get more than 3 per minute (60/20 = 3).

You will need to run more users or make the test shorter.